# Why am I getting PermissionError [Errno 13] when attempting to write to log in Flask hosted by Apache?

Tags: python, apache, flask, python-logging

I am running Flask 1.1.4 via Python 3.5.3, hosted via an Apache 2 server on Debian Stretch. I am attempting to log various messages from the program, using the python logging module. This works normally. However, if I restart the Apache server using `sudo service apache2 restart`, the Flask application errors out with `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: (log file name)`. Is this an issue anyone else has run into?

Comment: What are the permissions on the log file?  Is it perhaps owned by root?

Comment: @JohnGordon Permissions are initially 644, and it is owned www-data, the apache user. Now, investigating it, after I restart apache the permissions become 664 and owned by root. I just didn't realize it before because `ls -l` has a delay in reporting the change. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was a `cron` process that was editing the ownership of all files in my log folder to root. Once the program was restarted and needed to re-obtain the file reference, it was unable to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a permissions issue, this usually happens (happened to me a few times) if you are using a relative path for the log file.

The current working directory for an app running with mod_wsgi is not the directory the the app is in. If you are using a relative path for the log file you can try to use absolute path instead.

More info here: https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/master/user-guides/application-issues.html#application-working-directory